# Why listview is taking more space inside scroll view in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin

I have label title header, listview and button. All the controls need to scroll in the page. But Listview is taking more space when placed inside scroll view. Could anyone faced the issue like this?

Comment: ListView already has a scroll no need to put it inside another

Comment: I don't agree. There are cases when one could have multiple UI elements (including a list view) and because they don't fit the screen I need to put everything in a scroll view. This means that I have to have scroll inside scroll. If the user wants to scroll to get to a button/label/etc, he/she will touch outside the list view; if he/she wants to see a different row in the table then he/she would touch the inside of the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Listview is already have a scrolling behaviour. Why using a view have scrolling property inside into another scrollview..?   You can use Scrollview, if you have more than one listviews in your page.
 If you still want to use bath views try to set this property of listview  **HasUnevenRows="True"**

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, it is generally a bad idea to have a ListView inside a ScrollView as stated [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2857/listview-inside-scrollview).

That being said, I replicated this issue and got the page to stop stretching by adding RowHeight to the ListView.

```
<ScrollView BackgroundColor="Black">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
            <Label Text="BEFORE"/>
            <ListView BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                      RowHeight="40">
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>mono</x:String>
                        <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                        <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                        <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                        <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                        <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                        <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                        <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                        <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>
            </ListView>
            <Label Text="AFTER"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```